# Will barcodes generated by SharePoint guarantee that it will uniquely identify the item when migrate the list to different or same tenat

Tags: sharepoint-online, barcodes

I know that I can enable barcodes in SharePoint online, by following these steps inside the "In Place Records Management" feature. we can activate in Site Collection Administration > Site Collection Features > In Place Records Management. Within List Settings > Information management policy settings > Item > Enable Barcodes.

Now the barcode generated will uniquely identify the items inside the list. but what will happen if we want to migrate this list to another tenant or to another site within the same tenant? will the barcodes still valid, or we might get duplicate barcodes when generating new ones inside the destination site? and will we be able to retreive the item using the old barcodes?